# Aligning two adjacent numbered equations central to the vertical, and the horizontal

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, alignment

So I have an issue aligning two equations which I wish to label/number. I wish to place the equations adjacent to each other, with equidistant spacing in the horizontal (between the equations and the page maxima), and also aligned such that the equal-signs of both equations are in the same line of action horizontally. It may be easier to show you...

These are my three, inadequate, solutions thus far:

Solution 1):

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
    \vec{B}_{trap}(\vec{J}_c, \vec{r}) = k \mu_o \vec{J}_c \ \vec{\hat{r}}
  \end{equation}\break
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
    k = \frac{t}{2a}{\rm{ln}}\left ( \frac{a}{t} + \sqrt{1 + \left ( \frac{a}{t}\right )^{2}} \right )
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
```

Solution 2):

```
\begin{align*}
    \vec{B}_{trap}(\vec{J}_c, \vec{r}) = k \mu_o \vec{J}_c \ \vec{\hat{r}} \label{eq:btrap}
   & & k = \frac{t}{2a}{\rm{ln}}\left ( \frac{a}{t} + \sqrt{1 + \left ( \frac{a}{t}\right )^{2}} \right ) \\
\end{align*}
```

Solution 3):

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{equation}
    \vec{B}_{trap}(\vec{J}_c, \vec{r}) = k \mu_o \vec{J}_c \ \vec{\hat{r}}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    k = \frac{t}{2a}{\rm{ln}}\left ( \frac{a}{t} + \sqrt{1 + \left ( \frac{a}{t}\right )^{2}} \right )
  \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

Which typesets as so:

[image: Image denoting the three methods outlined above; first utilising <code>minipage</code>, second <code>align</code>, and third <code>multicols</code>.]

As you can see, method 1 and 3 produce numbered and referenced equations, as I need, as they both support the equation environment, however they also are not aligned in the horizontal plane - the equals signs do not share the same line of action horizontally. Whilst the `align` method allows this horizontal alignment I have failed to reference more than one equation as it can only handle one `\ref{eq1}`. I need to stay away from using `tabular` or `array` as my thesis document would pick up these equations as a table and list them in the 'tables' section of my document. I think so far the best method is align* but I am unable to produce references and numbered equations with that method (which again, must be seen as equations or my 'equations' page will not list them)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: your statement about avoiding tabular isn't correct, you may or may not want to use tabular (or array) but neither force the use of a float and the `table` environment or an entry in the list of tables.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's messing up your first, `minipage`-based solution is an inappropriate choice of widths. Also, don't use the `[t]` location specifiers for the `minipage` environments -- you want both equations *centered vertically* on the `=` symbols, right?

Also, note that I replaced `{\rm{ln}}` with `\ln`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\numberwithin" macro
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % optional

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

\noindent % <-- new
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth} % <-- new
\begin{equation}
\vec{B}_{\mathrm{trap}}(\vec{J}_c, \vec{r}) = 
    k \mu_o \vec{J}_c \hat{\vec{r}}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
k = \frac{t}{2a}\ln\biggl( \frac{a}{t} + 
    \sqrt{1 + \Bigl( \frac{a}{t}\Bigr)^{\!2}}\, \biggr)
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy to do this without adding unwanted spaces and having all the features of math displays.

Here's a quite general version. The optional argument to `halfequation` (default `0.5`) is the fraction of the width reserved for the equation.

In this particular case it seems best to reserve more for the larger equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{halfequation}[1][0.5]
 {\vcenter\bgroup
  \hsize=#1\displaywidth
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
  \begin{equation}}
 {\end{equation}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\[
\begin{halfequation}[0.4]\label{a}
  \vec{B}_{\mathrm{trap}}(\vec{J}_c, \vec{r}) = k \mu_o \vec{J}_c \, \vec{\hat{r}}
\end{halfequation}
\begin{halfequation}[0.6]\label{b}
  k = \frac{t}{2a}\ln\left ( \frac{a}{t} + \sqrt{1 + \left ( \frac{a}{t}\right )^{2}} \right )
\end{halfequation}
\]
\lipsum*[5]

\clearpage

\lipsum*[4]
  \begin{equation}
    k = \frac{t}{2a}\ln\left ( \frac{a}{t} + \sqrt{1 + \left ( \frac{a}{t}\right )^{2}} \right )
  \end{equation}
\lipsum*[5]

\end{document}
```

I added another page to show that the vertical spacings are the same.

[image]