# How do I write two equations side-by-side, with each equation numbered and with text in between?

Tags: math-mode, equations

The closest I could get is:

```
\documentclass{iopart}

\usepackage{iopams}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{.38\textwidth}
        \begin{equation} \label{eq:ComptonWavelength}
            E'_\gamma = \frac{E_\gamma}{1 + \frac{E_\gamma}{m_e c^2}(1 - \cos{\theta})}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth} \hfill
        \text{or}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.38\textwidth}
        \begin{equation}
            \Delta\lambda = \frac{h}{m_e c^2}(1 - \cos{\theta})
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

but the they aren't aligned perfectly and require tweaking the minipage widths which seems like a very inelegant non-LaTeX solution.

I've tried `\align`, `\multicols` and `\minipage`, but they all have problems related to vertical alignment or equation numbering.

Comment: Welcome with the users of TeX.SE. You can use `\intertext`.

Comment: How will that help?

Comment: Here there is an answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471814/aligning-two-adjacent-numbered-equations-central-to-the-vertical-and-the-horizo

Comment: @Sebastiano After trying this, there is still some vertical misalignment.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and could you put your full compilable code? Thanks.

Comment: How should I edit it?

Comment: Start with `\documentclass` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: The class `iopart` and the package `iopams` do not seem to be standard. Can you reproduce your problem in a standard class (such as `article`) and with standard packages?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If that is what you had in mind, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align} \label{eq:ComptonWavelength}
        \Delta\lambda &= \frac{h}{m_e c^2}(1 - \cos{\theta)}
\intertext{or}
    \theta &= \arccos{\biggl(1 + m_e c^2 \biggl(\frac{1}{E_\gamma} - \frac{1}{E'_\gamma} \biggr) \biggr)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

If you want the vertical spacing around the "or" to be less, you can use `\shortintertext` instead of `\intertext`, but then you need the package `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`.

To place the equations side by side (I do not recommend this), you can try two `minipage`s with `[t]` alignment:

[image]

But you'll need a `\vphantom{\bigg(}` so that the tops line up.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:ComptonWavelength}
   \vphantom{\bigg(}\Delta\lambda = \frac{h}{m_e c^2}(1 - \cos{\theta)}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
  \text{or\quad}  \theta = \arccos{\biggl(1 + m_e c^2 \biggl(\frac{1}{E_\gamma} - \frac{1}{E'_\gamma} \biggr) \biggr)}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

You'll have to play around with the widths of the `minipage`s. But I think it looks cramped all on one line.

Comment: Kindly can you edit, please, your code, that are there two little (( and ))? :-) Use you Mac retina :-)? :-)

Comment: I want the equations to be on the same line (i.e. side-by-side). The brackets have been fixed.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Ha! Good point. I used OP's code. Fixed now.

Comment: @LouieAtkins-Turkish The code of Sandy G is correct. Where is it written "on the same line (i.e. side-by-side)" in your question?

Comment: The main issue is them being horizontally aligned! I want them to be side-by-side.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I wrote "on the same line" originally. But I've clarified that now.

Comment: @LouieAtkins-Turkish: I updated my response. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: hmm, it didn't seem to work for me. They're still not aligned properly...

Comment: @LouieAtkins-Turkish: Could you be more specific? The equations are perfectly aligned for me. Also, just a suggestion, this site strongly discourages language that may be considered offensive; you may want to delete your last comment.

Comment: Ah sorry. And for me, they weren't aligned when using your code. The second equation is higher than the first equation.

Comment: There's also an error about an overfull hbox?

Comment: The problem is most likely related to the `iopart` class or `iopams` package (which I do not have). Can you reproduce the problem on your end using the entire code I provided (including `\documentclass`)?

Comment: @LouieAtkins-Turkish: Your `.38\textwidth` is probably causing the overfull box.

Comment: It works with standard document class. I wonder if it's just unfixable with iopart/iopams? Also, what x\textwidth would you suggest?

Comment: @LouieAtkins-Turkish: Recommendation would depend on your font size, page width and other factors. Honestly, I think vertical alignment would look better. But you can try fixing your alignment by using only 2 `minipage`s and attaching the "or" to the second one as I did in my example. Then adjust the `\textwidth` multipliers to total about .95.

Comment: Equations misalign when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{float,caption,hypcap}

%set up a command to insert a table equation number
\providecommand{\numberTblEq}[1]{\refstepcounter{tblEqCounter}\label{#1}\thetag{\thetblEqCounter}}
\begin{document}
    \newcounter{tblEqCounter} %create a counter

    \begin{equation}\label{eqtop}   a=b+c \end{equation}

    \setcounter{tblEqCounter}{\theequation} %at the start of the table, set the counter to equation numbering
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
            $\Delta\lambda = \frac{h}{m_e c^2}(1 - \cos{\theta)}$ & \numberTblEq{eq1}& text between& %set the equation number 
            $\theta = \arccos{\biggl(1 + m_e c^2 \biggl(\frac{1}{E_\gamma} - \frac{1}{E'_\gamma} \biggr) \biggr)}$ & \numberTblEq{eq2}\\ %labels are optional
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \setcounter{equation}{\thetblEqCounter} %at the end of the table, set the equation numbering to the counter

    Yet another equation:
    \begin{equation}\label{eq3}     d=b+c \end{equation}

    This is a ref to the eqn at the top: \ref{eqtop} ,to two eqns: \eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq2}. And the other one: \ref{eq3}.
\end{document}
```

[image]